# On pitfalls of robust commands

Tags: macros, expansion, etoolbox, xparse

These days, I’m more and more defining *robust* commands, e.g., using `\newrobustcmd` ([`etoolbox`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) package) or `\NewDocumentCommand` ([`xparse`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) package). Robust commands seem advantageous to me in many respects and, in fact, other people do think the same. To quote from the section of the `xparse` package documentation dedicated to the tools supporting the definition of non-robust (i.e. fully expandable) commands:

> There are *very rare* occasion[s] when it may be useful to create functions using a fully-expandable argument grabber. To support this, `xparse` can create expandable functions as well as the usual robust ones. […] This facility should only be used when *absolutely necessary*; if you do not understand when this might be, *do not use these functions*!

Yet I’ve made the experience that robust commands have their pitfalls. Consider, for instance, the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd*{\test}[1]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{blank}{not blank}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\test{\empty}}

\end{document}
```

The output is rather unsatisfying since the decision of `\test` on the nature of its argument is context-dependent:

[image]

What shall I do in this and similar situations? Resort to `\newcommand`?

Comment: Of course, the real issue here is the implementation of `\section`, which would be much better to write its argument `\unexpanded`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Definitely true! But how to ensure that all commands with moving arguments behave this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you encounter in your example is based on the fact that arguments of robust commands are not shielded from expansion at all. As a consequence, `\test` examines two different arguments: the token `\empty` in the section heading and the empty string in the table of contents. Nonetheless, you need not resort to defining `\test` as a fully expandable command. Use `\newcommand` in conjunction with `\protecting` ([`etoolbox`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) package) to obtain a command that will be expanded only once:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \protecting{\ifblank{#1}{blank}{not blank}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\test{\empty}}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: I'm troubled: did you just answer yourself calling yourself "you"? (third word)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: OK, probably it would be better if I wrote ‘The problem I encounter in my example …’ to emphasize the fact that this is a self-answer. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, I should have put a smiley in my last comment.  It really doesn't matter, I just found that odd :). Nice question and answer, by the way.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: :-)