# Robust commands

Tags: macros, best-practices, examples, robust-commands

What is the primary reason to `\protect` new definitions or macros, or use `\DeclareRobustCommand` rather than just `\def`?
(If it is primarily to do with better error messages, I personally can live with the Prolog ``No''. If it's better to start using it everywhere, which are the packages to load and best practices?)

WANTED: A one sentence answer I can give other people about why `\DeclareRobustCommand` is used somewhere but elsewhere there is `\def`.

MOTIVATION: Sometimes you base code on an existing macro and put in an article. `\DeclareRobustCommand` is sometimes used. Then a coauthor or an editor replies: Why do you need this complicated looking code? What do you tell them?

Comment: A good starting point: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764) and [On pitfalls of robust commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61762/5764).

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` is defined in the latex format, not in a package.  It's not the difference between good and bad error messages, but rather the difference between things working and getting an error message. But I think it's probably a duplicate of the questions Werner lists

Comment: If you do not define a command to be robust then the user has to use `\protect` in front of the command in all moving arguments such as headings captions, writing to files etc, so the command is more complicated for the _user_.

Comment: D.C., your last comment answers the question. Can you post it as an answer so I can checkmark it, closing the question? This was ultimately what I was looking for: a one sentence answer I can give other people about why \DeclareRobustCommand is used somewhere but elsewhere \def is used.

Comment: By the way, if I'm a journal copy editor, I'd reject *any* document using `\def`, asking to use `\newcommand` or similar method; this includes `\DeclareRobustCommand`, but only if preceded by a `\newcommand` for checking definability of the command (unless comments explain why the author wants to *redefine* a command).

Comment: BTW, any reason to use something from the etoolbox package if working with robust commands?

Comment: And I'd reject *any* document using `\newcommand`, asking to use `\def` or similar method. Because `\newcommand` doesn't work in plain TeX.

Comment: @GuidoJorg: If you use `etoolbox` you can apply `\robustify\mycommand` and it will be robust after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` If you do not define a command to be robust then the user has to use `\protect` in front of the command in all moving arguments such as headings captions, writing to files etc, so the command is more complicated for the user. – David Carlisle Mar 5 at 9:22''

This was ultimately what I was looking for: a one sentence answer I can give other people about why \DeclareRobustCommand is used somewhere.